# Why is my git log output getting mangled when I pipe it?

Tags: git, shell, pipe

If I let Git use its built-in `head`-style log truncation, I get exactly what I expect:

```
$ git log --color=always --graph -5                                                                               

* 5abf1e7b0aba45e895bbe5b235f2326ad808ad30 (HEAD -> feature/blahblah, origin/feature/blahblah) blah blah last commit message
* c7b065e3d06ed8066ded283c2feec17e9f5a95d6 whitelist the new field
* 6b4332b951b2b37dec4c0fc67defb778dbdc29d7 add blah blah model
* 323c7570388f13aad8144292ebeb31187eb1c742 add blah blah to the database
* bceae36bda53b48679556eb00ee8321f1c8392e6 (origin/feature/yadayada, feature/yadayada) add blah blah to each blah blah
```

But if I use `head`, it removes the branch markers (which I want!):

```
$  git log --color=always --graph | head -5                                                                        

* 5abf1e7b0aba45e895bbe5b235f2326ad808ad30 blah blah last commit message
* c7b065e3d06ed8066ded283c2feec17e9f5a95d6 whitelist the new field
* 6b4332b951b2b37dec4c0fc67defb778dbdc29d7 add blah blah model
* 323c7570388f13aad8144292ebeb31187eb1c742 add blah blah to the database
* bceae36bda53b48679556eb00ee8321f1c8392e6 add blah blah to each blah blah
```

How can I avoid losing these branch markers when I pipe the output of `git-log` to another tool?

(I'm trying to pipe output to `fzf`, and in order to get things the way I want them, it needs to be reversed, but Git does not allow `--graph` and `--reverse` to be used together, so I must reverse the output with an outside utility like `tac` (actually `gtac` on macOS), which causes me to lose the branch markers, which is one of three main reasons I'm writing my own function instead of using the `fcs` example [here](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/wiki/examples).)

Comment: What version of git and what OS? I get very different results on OSX with git 2.14.3

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.11 (because of Karabiner), and Git version 2.16.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're referring specifically to the `(HEAD -> feature/foo)` decorations, which sometimes appear, and sometimes don't, somehow magically *automatically detecting* whether you have piped `git log` output through some other program.

These decorations are added under control of various flags, as described in [the `git log` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html):

> --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
>
>   Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If
>   *short*
>   is specified, the ref name prefixes
>   *refs/heads/*
>   ,
>   *refs/tags/*
>   and
>   *refs/remotes/*
>   will not be printed. If
>   *full*
>   is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed.
>   **If *auto* is specified**
>   , then if the output is going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if
>   *short*
>   were given, otherwise no ref names are shown. The default option is
>   *short*
>   .

(the boldface here is mine).

Older versions of Git are not as fancy, and some older versions default to `no` rather than `auto` or `short`, but the option has been around for a long time.  Moreover, you can configure, in your per-user `git config --global` settings, your own default.  You probably either have a version of Git that defaults to `auto` (this one is my bet) or have configured your setting to `auto`.